# Why is the mysqli->$errno being set to 0 in the middle of the debugging?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Today I am faced with a bizarre situation. I have been searching for a definition but unfortunately, I couldn't find any.

In my PHP code, I am inserting a row into a database table. When I try to insert a duplicate primary key as part of debugging a recent issue, I can see the duplicate primary key exception in the `mysqli` object as expected.

However, `mysqli->$errno`, `mysqli->$error`, `mysqli->error_list` are immediately being reset to empty which I cannot comprehend why.

This is part of the code that I am experiencing the issue with.

```php
$retry = 5;
do {
    $mysqli_result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if (mysqli_errno($conn) == 1213)    { /** Here I can observe the expected errno, error, error_list **/
        sleep(1); $retry--;
    } else
        $retry = 0;
} while ($retry);
/** Here - errno, error, error_list are reset to empty */
```

***Update***
I have also noticed that along with the change that I mentioned the `mysqli->$stat` is also changing. Or is it like when the stat is queried everything else is reset?

***Some additional info***

- This is an old project made using PHP 5.6 [95% compatible with up to PHP 7.2]. So I am using 7.2 in my local environment. Don't advise me to upgrade the whole project please, I know its already dead. I am just maintaining the project
- The variable `$conn` is global
- I am using vscode and compatible Xdebug extension for watching the variables
- I am observing this behaviour when there is a slight delay in stepping over the current statement.

Comment: May be better to store the error - it may be that the call to `mysqli_errno` is resetting the error code (as this function succeeds)

Comment: But In some cases it is working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to say this but it looks like the problem is that you are using an unsupported PHP version. The broken `mysqli::$stat` property was removed in PHP 7.4. The solution is to upgrade your PHP version.

When triggering any MySQLi function the error and error properties are reset. You have to check it immediately after calling each function.

For example:

```
$mysqli->stat();
if($mysqli->error) {
  // ...
```

However, I would strongly recommend to forget about ever using `error` and `errno` properties. Just enable automatic MySQLi error reporting and stop checking for errors manually.

When using xDebug the properties will never be shown to you correctly due to this MySQLi bug.

I know you can't afford it now, but please always consider using PDO rather than MySQLi. PDO is much better and easier.

Comment: Aah. Thank you very much for your valuable information. I now atleast now where to start

Comment: Thanks again man I am making this the accepted answer. This has been bugging me for two days. I now know how to fix my problem.